# Can't get out of the program through code

Tags: python, python-2.7, exit

I am trying to stop my program in a specific spot and it won't shut.

I used this to stop the program:

```
Raise SystemExit(0)
```

Comment: That's not Python code is it? Should be `sys.exit(0)`... Which isn't a raised exception

Comment: It is python code, i tried     sys.exit(0)      aswell but it won't stop the proccess.

Comment: It is not valid Python code. Questions seeking debugging help require a [mcve]

Comment: Is It possible that the program won't shut because of running threads?

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do would work, except that `Raise` and `raise` are not the same thing, just like `pRinT` and `print` are not the same thing. Python is case-sensitive. So:

```
$ python
>>> Raise SystemExit(0)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But:

```
$ python
>>> raise SystemExit(0)
$
```

That being said, you almost never want to raise `SystemExit` directly. As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) explain, this exception is there to be used by [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) under the covers, not for you to use directly.

So, [as Arthur Dent explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50340636/908494), a better solution is:

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.exit(0)
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use:

```
import sys
sys.exit(1)
```